# Scroll na pagina adiciona a classe "ACTIVE" ao menu

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Olá, estou tendo dificuldade para fazer com que o jquery adicione uma classe *active* ao menu que esta *fixed* no topo.

quem quiser ver o site para entender melhor segue o link.

[Site Safira](http://www.safiralimpeza.com.br/)

Quero que a classe seja adicionada quando eu der scroll na pagina e estiver passando pela section em questao, se estou na section "Y" , o menu fica active no "Y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

Explicação:

- cria uma função `addClass` para atribuir a classe ao `li` do menu certo
- colocar em cache os `li`'s do menu e as posições de cada `section`, bem como cada elemento `section`
- escutar o evento `scroll` e procurar o elemento do menu que corresponde (`i`) à ultima `section` que têm a posição inferior ao `scroll` (ou seja: o `scroll` tenha passado por ela). Aqui  (`if (scroll > this)`) pode ajustar com um valor numérico para que o if dispare mais cedo ou mais tarde. Por exemplo: `if (scroll > this - 100)` vai atribuir a classe um pouco mais cedo.
- escutar o clic também e adicionar classe correspondente

jQuery / JavaScript

```
function addClass(el) {
    menu.removeClass('active');
    $(el).addClass('active');
};

var menu = $('#meuMenu .nav li');
var sectionPositions = $('section').map(function(){
    return $(this).position().top;
});
var sections = $('section');
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var currentElement;
    $(sectionPositions).each(function (i) {
        if (scroll > this - 50) currentElement = menu[i];
    });
    currentElement && addClass(currentElement);
});
menu.on('click', function () {
    addClass(this);
});
```

Agora só precisa adicionar no CSS (ou usar o que já tem):

```
.active{
    border: 1px green solid; # ou outra propriedade que goste
}
```

Pode também mudar o CSS diretamente no elemento, usando assim:

```
function addClass(el) {
    menu.find('a').css('color', 'inherit');
    $(el).find('a').css('color', 'blue');
};
```

**Note:** Você têm um erro na linha 129 do ficheiro index:

Mude:

```
$(nav navbar-nav menu a).removeClass('active');
```

para o código em baixo (com aspas):

```
    $('nav navbar-nav menu a').removeClass('active');
//    ^                     ^
```

Comment: Perfeito sergio, queria saber agora como eu faço para tirar a classe ao voltar para o topo da pagina.

Comment: @manzetti.denis, quando? Qual deve ser a causa que faz tirar a class e ir para o cimo de novo? Pode explicar melhor?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(a[href^='#']).click(function(){
$(nav navbar-nav menu a).removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
return false;


 });
```

Comment: Seria interessante explicar sua solução para deixar sua resposta mais completa.

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa detectar o click no seu menu e adicionar uma classe, no caso `active`, como citado, exemplo:

```
$('#meuMenu ul li').click(function(){
    $('#meuMenu ul li').removeClass('active');    
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqwZ8/)**

Comment: certo, porem quero que a classe seja adicionada quando eu der scroll na pagina e estiver passando pela section em questao, se estou na section "Y" , o menu fica active no "Y"

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll - JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/