# Conforme Scroll e aplicar classe no link especifico no menu

Tags: jquery, menu

Já vi o efeito em alguns sites! Porém não tenho nenhuma noção de como faze-lo!

O efeito trabalha em um conjunto, formado pelo menu o corpo da pagina e a classe!

Digamos que eu tenha um menu com três abas, sendo A B C.
Quando a pagina é rolada pra baixo - creio eu que - a página é "inspecionada" e o script verifica em qual ponto da página o usuário se encontra! E caso ele passe do ponto A pro B uma classe é "transferida" da aba A para a aba B.

Digamos que esse efeito seja uma borda inferior, então se o usuário passar o ponto limite, a borda também se muda de hospedeiro, passando de A para B! E caso o usuário alcance o ponto C a borda vai para o C, e caso usuário retorno ao ponto A, a borda também retornar ao ponto A.

> No link a seguir existe um exemplo real do que estou tentando dizer.
>
> > Rolem a pagina para baixo e verão que a borda quadriculada entre as abas muda de lugar conforme alcança o ponto referente a aba no corpo do documento ::
> >
> > > https://www.createwebsite.net/freebies/atlas/index.html

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não é isso não!! Vou procurar um link que tenha algum exemplo!!1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento adicionei um link com um exemplo! Vale dizer que da pra achar esse efeito na internet porém o intuito da pergunta é aprender como se faz!

Comment: Ivan veja se isso funciona http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17457/3635

Comment: Esse link se encaixa perfeito na resposta! http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

Comment: Ivan me parece que esse http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17491/3635 também, ele só não adicionou um exemplo LIVE, mas é o mesmo efeito, a diferença é que não usou `transition` no CSS, mas até então isso é só um efeito extra